# curl gives 400 error but works in postman?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am using codeigniter-3 ,inside controller i am hitting one external API it's giving 400 error but same curl request if i hit in postman it's working fine can you please help me did i miss anything ..?

**CURL REQUEST in postman**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://armycalling.com/baligaz-api/api/userapi/login' \
--header 'x-api-key: ccccc' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YmFsaWdheiFAIyQ=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: ci_session=f3630b226e539f4aa079e980e23cc730609a1627' \
--data-raw '{
    "email" : "dummy@gmail.com",
    "password" : "dummy.srk"
}'
```

`usercontroller.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            //phpinfo();
            $url = 'http://localhost/login';
            $u_name = $this->input->post('username');
            $password= $this->input->post('password');
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            $data = [
                'email'=>$u_name, 
                'password'=>$password
            ];
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                        'x-api-key: ccccc',
                        'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YmFsaWdheiFAIyQ=',
                        'Content-Type: Application/json',
                        'Cookie: ci_session=6dc4b8f72e2953c590ff503bd47f52ecfa158c79'
            ));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            return print($httpcode);
            curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: _Hint_ There is `</>` icon in Postman that allows you to export request in PHP script

Comment: Not sure if PHP cURL makes a POST request based on setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` alone, try and add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: Please note that if your system is case sensitive, then you are sending wrong (lowercase) `x-api-key` value

Comment: @CBroe, if i use CURL_POST it's giving method not allowed 405.

Comment: @Justinas, i changed but still getting same 400

Comment: I get a `401 Unauthorized` using the above credentials but with different curl configuration.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, i have updated the password can you please check

Comment: `[response] => {"status":true,"message":"User login successful.","data":{"id":"22","user_id":"baligaz_595689","first_name":"Rasa","last_name":"Kumar"`..... etc I'll post the code shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting this request to use a cookie session and sending the username/password in a POST request yields a successful login.

```
function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL, $headers=false ){
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    session_write_close();

    /* Initialise curl request object - these should be OK as-is */
    $curl=curl_init();

    /* Define standard options */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
    
    /* enhanced debug */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );
    

    /* Assign runtime parameters as options to override defaults if needed. */
    if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
        foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
    }
    
    /* send any headers with the request that are needed */
    if( isset( $headers ) && is_array( $headers ) ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    }

    /* Execute the request and store responses */
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'status'    =>  curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );
    
    rewind( $vbh );
    $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );
    curl_close( $curl );
    
    return $res;
}


# create a temporary file somewhere to store cookie data.
# Using the system temp directory should mean automatic 
# deletion of these files in time.
$cookiestore=tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), '_cookiejar_' );


$url='http://armycalling.com/baligaz-api/api/userapi/login';


$headers=array(
    'x-api-key: BALIGAZ@123',
    'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YmFsaWdheiFAIyQ='
);

$args=array(
    'email'     =>  'rasakumar.srk@gmail.com',
    'password'  =>  'rasakumar.srk'
);

/*
    Mark the request as a new Cookie session - subsequent requests
    would have different options without CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION
*/
$options=array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   =>  true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      =>  $cookiestore,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       =>  $cookiestore,
    CURLOPT_POST            =>  true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      =>  $args
);      

/* 
    Make the request with specified config options
*/
$res=curl( $url, $options, $headers );

/* 
    If the request is successful a 200 OK status code will be received
    so we can then proceed to work with the response data.
    
    If the request fails, using the returned info & verbose properties
    of the response will show useful debug info.
*/
if( $res->status==200 ){
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $res->response, true ) );
}
```

This yields:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "User login successful.",
  "data": {
    "id": "22",
    "user_id": "baligaz_595689",
    "first_name": "Rasa",
    "last_name": "Kumar",
    "email": "rasakumar.srk@gmail.com",
    "password": "529f263ebb230b4709003bb0f7457f90",
    "phone": "73339190384",
    "profile_img": "http://armycalling.com/baligaz-api/profile_image/baligaz_595689_app_one.png",
    "role": "1",
    "station_id": "HP Petrols",
    "forgot_otp": "",
    "created": "2022-06-24 04:47:13",
    "created_by": null,
    "modified": "2022-06-30 23:38:15",
    "updated_by": "baligaz_595689",
    "login_completed": null,
    "status": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's working fine can you give me some details about your answer

Comment: A lot of the parameters within that `curl` function are probably superfluous - the important part is the use of the runtime config for the cookie handling and the use of the POST method and POST data. You should change the password and other sensitive pieces of data as a matter of priority